# Break lines at specified points with awk

Tags: awk, split

I have a file with multiple lines in the following form:

```
name1    a1    b3    c6    a3    b4    c9
name2    a7    b8    c7    a9    b10   c13
name3    a12   b9    c8
name4    a4    b34   c19   a7    b2    c10    a3    b5    c67
```

I need to break the lines after the letters repeat (i.e. after each a,b,c), but have the original name (field 1) retained:

```
name1    a1    b3    c6    
name1    a3    b4    c9
name2    a7    b8    c7    
name2    a9    b10   c13
name3    a12   b9    c8
name4    a4    b34   c19   
name4    a7    b2    c10    
name4    a3    b5    c67
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1"\t"$i }' file
```

but the `i++` incorporates each field, is there a way to group them?

Thank you.

Comment: Can the letters come out of order? `c2` `a3` `b1`?

Comment: @Mark Setchell yes they can

Comment: Will they always repeat or could there be lines with no repetition?

Comment: Might we get `z1` `q2` `a1` `d7` `r0` `z2` ?

Comment: @starter5: Could you please try solution provided by me as follows too once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for your post! It does indeed work, but I have updated the initial input file to include different number of repeats.

Comment: @Mark Setchell -- they will always repeat, but the length of the repeat is variable (please see update)

Comment: @starter5 : if you want to break line after every a,b,c or any first one ? see below post, it gives expected o/p

Answer (score 0):

@starter5: Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{V["a"];V["b"];V["c"]} /name/{R=$0;next} {Q=$0;gsub(/[[:digit:]]/,"",Q)} (Q in V){if(!W[Q]++){A++}} $0{if(A==1 && $0 && R){$0=R OFS $0};printf("%s %s",$0,(A==3?"\n":OFS));;if(A==3){A="";delete W}}' RS='[ +|\n]'  Input_file
```

Following is the NON-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
                V["a"];
                V["b"];
                V["c"]
          }
                /name/{
                        R=$0;
                        next
                      }
          {
                Q=$0;
                gsub(/[[:digit:]]/,"",Q)
          }
                (Q in V){
                                if(!W[Q]++){
                                                A++
                                           }
                        }
                $0      {
                                if(A==1 && $0 && R){
                                                        $0=R OFS $0
                                                   };
                                printf("%s %s",$0,(A==3?"\n":OFS));;
                                if(A==3)           {
                                                        A="";
                                                        delete W
                                                   }
                        }
    ' RS='[ +|\n]'    Input_file
```

So let's say we have following Input_file(where I changed the last line) to test if a,b,c are not coming in sequence, so it will NOT break line till three of them found, have a look to it and let me know then.

```
cat  Input_file
name1    a1    b3    c6    a3    b4    c9
name2    a7    b8    c7    a9    b10   c13
name3    a12   b9    c8
name4    a4    b34   a19   a7    b2    c10    a3    b5    c67
```

Output will be as follows.

```
name1 a1  b3  c6
name1 a3  b4  c9
name2 a7  b8  c7
name2 a9  b10  c13
name3 a12  b9  c8
name4 a4  b34  a19  a7  b2  c10
name4 a3  b5  c67
```

Comment: The _output_ you're shown does not match that of the OP or what I get, the same as the OP, running your `awk` _program_. There should be three separate `name4` lines and you are only shown two.

Comment: @user3439894: Kindly read my statement clearly along with OP, so I made a change in Input_file and didn't make all a,b,c in order so it printed the lines till it find all 3 matches of a,b,c in lines. If we use exact file like OP posted it should work with that too. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to break the lines after the letters repeat (i.e. after each
>   a,b,c), but have the original name (field 1) retained:

**Input**

```
$ cat file
name1    a1    b3    c6    a3    b4    c9
name2    a7    b8    c7    a9    b10   c13
name3    a12   b9    c8
name4    a4    b34   c19   a7    b2    c10    a3    b5    c67
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'function _p(){print $1,s; s=""; split("",p)}{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){ c=substr($i,1,1);if(c in p)_p(); s = (s?s OFS:"") $i; p[c] }_p()}' file
name1 a1 b3 c6
name1 a3 b4 c9
name2 a7 b8 c7
name2 a9 b10 c13
name3 a12 b9 c8
name4 a4 b34 c19
name4 a7 b2 c10
name4 a3 b5 c67
```

**Better Readable version**

```
awk '
   function _p()
   {
              print $1,s;
              s=""; 
              split("",p)
   }
   {
      for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      { 
              c=substr($i,1,1); 
              if(c in p)_p();
              s = (s?s OFS:"") $i; 
              p[c] 
      }
      _p()
   }
    ' file
```

**OR**

```
$ awk 'function _p(){print $1,s; s=p=""}{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){ c=substr($i,1,1); if(c==p)_p(); s = (s?s OFS:"") $i; if(!p)p=c }_p()}' file
name1 a1 b3 c6
name1 a3 b4 c9
name2 a7 b8 c7
name2 a9 b10 c13
name3 a12 b9 c8
name4 a4 b34 c19
name4 a7 b2 c10
name4 a3 b5 c67
```

**Better Readable version**

```
awk '
     function _p()
     {
        print $1,s; 
        s=p=""
     }
     {
        for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        { 
            c=substr($i,1,1); 
            if(c==p)_p(); 
            s = (s?s OFS:"") $i; 
            if(!p)p=c 
        }
          _p()
     }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{                                   # for any record
    printf $1                       # print name
    c=substr($2,1,1);               # first letter of group
    printf OFS $2                   # first part of first group
    for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) {          # for all the rest fields
        if(index($i,c) != 1)        # if next group has not started
            printf OFS $i           # print this part on same line
        else                        # otherwise
            printf ORS $1 OFS $i    # print name and this part on next line
    }                               # done for all fields
    printf ORS                      # move to next line
}                                   # done for this record
```

This does not work if some letter repeats *within* a group. For example, it won't work for `a3 b5 a4 c6 a5 b6 a0 b9` where groups of `a b a c` are present.

This can be run like:

```
awk '{ printf $1; c=substr($2,1,1); printf OFS $2; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) if(index($i,c)!=1) printf OFS $i; else printf ORS $1 OFS $i; printf ORS}' file
```